# What is the probability of an edge?

Tags: graph-theory

We call a graph $G$ $(p, α)$-jumbled if, for every induced subgraph holds; here p and α are real numbers with $0<p<1≤α$, and $e(H)$ is the number of edges in H. We show that a (p, α)-jumbled graph behaves in many ways like a random graph with edge probability $p$, and some aspects of this similarity are examined.

What is the probability of an edge from a graph? How do I calculate it? Please give me an example. Thank you.

Comment: By definition the probability, or weight, of an edge, is the **conditional** probability of the event at the end of the edge happening **given that** all the events before that edge have occurred.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: The question is very unclear. Where have you seen "the probability of an edge"? Give us some context, please!

Comment: We call a graph G (p, α)-jumbled if, for every induced subgraph  holds; here p and α are real numbers with 0<p<1≤α, and e(H) is the number of edges in H. We show that a (p, α)-jumbled graph behaves in many ways like a random graph with edge probability p, and some aspects of this similarity are examined.

Comment: You should have said that from the beginning. The question was indeed very misleading!

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

A random graph with edge probability $p$ means a graph with a given number of vertices, where:

> For any two vertices the probability that there is an edge connecting
>   them is $p$, independently of the other edges.

You have therefore a set $\Omega$ made of all possible simple graphs on your set of $n$ vertices, and the probability of each graph is $p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$ where $k$ is the number of edges and $N$ is the number of potential edges $n\choose 2$.

Comment: Thanks man. You are the best. XD

Comment: Then p equals what?

Comment: In the text that you shared, $p$ is an arbitrary parameter - could be anything.